# Plain JS version for the jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have the following jQuery code (I have changed names of div and functions, not going to make much difference)

```
$(function(){
    $('#div1').bind('touchend',function(){
        function1();
        function2();
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('#div2').bind('touchend',function(){
        function1();
        function3();
    });
});
```

This is the plain JS version of it, which doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('touchend',function(){
    function1();
    function2();
},false);

document.getElementById('div2').addEventListener('touchend',function(){
    function1();
    function3();
},false);
```

If someone can explain what is the meaning of the jQuery version first, and then point out what mistake I made with the plain js version, I'll be grateful!

[In case if you're wondering why am I doing this, I need to remove jQuery from the phonegap app I'm building, so that the page loads faster :-)]

Comment: @BenniKa: was that comment meant as troll ? If not, you're dead wrong.

Comment: @BenniKa Sorry to inform you, but you couldn't be more wrong (Read like Chandler ;-))

Comment: Have you try ontouchend = function() {} as well? If it is suitable to use in your APP context of course.

Comment: @gillesc Yea I did.. But the answer I posted below works. Why it works, I don't know yet. Analyzing the code.

Comment: Cos the DOM is ready for this one, you forgot the equivalent of $(document).ready(); or in your original post $(function(){}); (short version)

Comment: Yeah, read the answer below.. thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work in any browser/DOM that supports *touch events*. The only thing I can figure here is that you miss the `DOMContentLoaded` event to invoke and therefore, try to get/query elements which are not ready yet.

So you should wrap your code into

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
}, false);
```

jQuery automatically does this for you, when you invoke `$(function() {});`. If you pass a function into `$()` its a shortcut for `$(document).ready(fnc)`

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why jquery code works then? I mean, there is no DOMContentLoaded there..
Edit: 
Cool, thanks for the edit. Understood :-)

Answer (score 1):

The code does exactly what yours is doing, just keeping the handlers separate, I think the only trouble you had was the lack of using

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
```

Which means the dom wasn't ready and getElementById would not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I read few other posts here, and this one pretty much nailed it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                      var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
                      var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
                      // event handler
                      var handler = function (event) {
                        function1();
                        function2();
                      };
                      var handler2 = function(event) {
                        function1();
                        function3();
                      };
                      // Bind the events
                      div1.addEventListener('touchend', handler, false);
                      div2.addEventListener('touchend',handler2,false);
                      }, false);
```

But if some one could explain me what is the flow and how the code works, my day is made :-)

Comment: this is basically like writting your jquery code inside the .ready() event. DOMContentLoaded ensures that the elements exist before trying to bind event listeners too them. Putting the handlers into anonymous functions before placing them in the touchend listeners is purely for readability

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain :-).. Still a newbie to jQuery :-).. Like to do stuff with JS only :-)